# Are too many books on a subject a boon or a bane?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, book-recommendation

> Are too many books on a subject a boon or a bane?

I am about to appear in a competitive exam in $3$ months for my PhD where one of the topics is complex analysis.

Background:Pure Mathematics

The questions will be of subjective type.

I am trying to learn complex analysis on my own.Though I studied it I am not so strong in it.

In the mean time whenever I am trying to solve the exercises,I am having difficulty in solving them.I am going on downloading books for the exam which will have good exercises.

The more books I am getting,instead of helping me they are making me anxious because there are so many to solve in such a short time.

What should I do now?I am unable to find out that particular book with good exercises that would help me in my exam.

I have bought Gamelin,Bak-Newmann,Shakarchi and Conway,but which should I choose between the three;Neither are helping me to solve the sample questions.Conway and Gamelin are so  difficult to solve.Should I get more books?

Please help me what should I do?Where is the problem lying?

Comment: I can't recommend books but I will tell you this, pick the easiest (for you) of the bunch and finish reading the whole book. The if you have time, you can move on to harder ones.

Comment: I've heard that the best book for complex analysis is A. I. Markushevich "Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable". It has 3 volumes, you might find there the things that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mainly need a book of exercises with solutions. No longer read theory ; come back to theory when a difficulty springs out in an exercice.

If your test checks plainly that the basics are known, make sure that you:

- (of course) are OK with complex numbers. For example the $n$th roots of unity, computation of modules and arguments with, as possible, a geometric view on the question (example: what are the module and argument of $e^{ia}+e^{ib}$  ?)
- are able to work on functions $Z=f(z)$ in a basic way, for example be able to compute the image of the imaginary axis by $Z=4z^2$, or the pre-image of the unit-circle.
- can switch between a vision $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and a vision $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ ; in particular, make sure you understand Cauchy-Riemann equations and what they mean (i.e., complex derivation is a similitude with ratio $|f'(z)|$, thus preserves angles),
- are apt at expanding series in an annulus (Laurent+Taylor expansions) and understand what it means,
- understand the principle of analytic continuation (with cuts, it means understanding what complex logarithm is and is useful at),
- master the meaning of complex integration over a contour and its application to the computation of integrals by the method of residues for simple contours,
- are able to use some basic theorems in a thorough manner: maximums' principle, Rouché's theorem, Liouville's theorem.

  Beyond that, it's specialization. For example, don't dwell into Picard's theorem,  conformal mapping, Schwarz-Christoffel, etc.

See the rich exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306892).

Comment: When I am searching in MSE for good books on Complex Analysis the ones which are recommend don't contain solutions ;So which one to choose ;Please help

Comment: An old book that has a rather simple approach "Complex variables and applications" by R. V. Churchill, Mc Graw Hill. Much more sophisticated but absolutely excellent, with many figures: "Applied and Computational Complex Analysis" by P. Henrici (2 volumes) Wiley Interscience

Comment: Do they all contain solutions as you suggested

Comment: @JeanMarie what source do you recommend to best learn analytic continuation properly? I've take a complex analysis course and read one or two big Rudin chapters on complex analysis but I've never come across it.

Comment: @Ben Stokes For many (corrected) exercices:  "Complex Variables" Schaum's  collection. Authors: Spiegel, Lipschutz, Schiller, Spellman

Comment: @juan arroyo Analytic continuation is well treated in the book of Henrici I have mentionned just before. See also the reference given at the end of my answer.